# Combining multiple rows in pandas dataframe with sparse values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After working on a pandas dataframe I have the following sparse situation

| Name | ParamA | ParamB | ParamC | ParamD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1.0 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| A | NULL | NULL | 3.0 | NULL |
| A | NULL | NULL | NULL | 6.0 |

What I want to have is combining multiple rows under the column 'Name' and substituting the NULL to the value present in the next rows (if multiple rows have something in ParamX then, take the last).

The output of the previous example would be:

| Name | ParamA | ParamB | ParamC | ParamD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1.0 | NULL | 3.0 | 6.0 |

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve in a simple way, a grouped `last()`:

```
df.groupby('Name',as_index=False).last()
```

prints:

```
  Name  ParamA  ParamB  ParamC  ParamD
0    A     1.0     NaN     3.0     6.0
```

No need for `apply`.